# Gauss's Cirlce Problem #lattice points in circle

Tags: reference-request

Can someone link me the proof that $E(r)/r^{1/2}$ -> infinity when $r$->infinity?
Where #lattice points in circle = $Pi*r^2+E(r)$

Comment: The original source is G.H. Hardy, On the Expression of a Number as the Sum of Two Squares, Quart. J. Math. 46, (1915), pp.263–283 . Doesn't seem to be online. This undergrad thesis http://www.math.rochester.edu/undergraduate/sums/reu/2005_galante-joseph.pdf repeats the argument.